# Passar para lambda/linq um foreach

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho esse método com um foreach dentro

```
[Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<MarkupListResponse>))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int resellerId)
        {
            var catalogs = _catalogService.GetAllByResellerId(resellerId).ToList();
            var model = new List<MarkupListResponse>();
            foreach (var catalog in catalogs)
            {
                model.Add(new MarkupListResponse()
                {
                    CreatedOn = catalog.CatalogDate,
                    CatalogId = catalog.Id,
                    ItemsQuantity = catalog.Items.Count
                });
            }

            return Ok(model);
        }
```

Nesse foreach possuo mais de 400 itens em **catalogs**. Como eu faço para pssar para uma lambda, pois acho que isso possa melhorar a performance, acho.

Estou usando Entity Framework para essas consultas e MVC.

Comment: Não, só piorará a performance. Já respondi sobre, pra vc inclusive: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53857/101

Comment: @Maniero, dentro do foreach, eu dou um **new**, ou seja, instancio a cada iteração o objeto **MarkupListResponse** e populo as propriedades da dele. Isso pode interferir na performance? Pois nesse loop, eu tenho uma péssima performance, entre outras nesse projeto.

Comment: Sim, mas nem sempre pode escapar disto. Em alguns sim, mas aí cabe uma análise profunda. Talvez tirar esse `ToList()` possa ajudar, mas não acho que muito. Se tá ruim, o problema deve ser outro porque 400 é pouca coisa.

Comment: Comece otimizando a sua query no banco, retorne apenas as informações que vai utilizar, já refletindo uma `List<MarkupListResponse>` e verifique os índices... É muito mais provável que o seu gargalo esteja nesse ponto do que no foreach...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, mas eu consegui performance apenas trocando o foreach pela lambda, conforme minha própria resposta. Vou fazer isso(segui sua orientação no banco) em outro gargalo que tenho, o qual originou meu primeiro post nesse assunto, mesmo que tenha conseguido melhora, mas ainda está muito lento, para a qde de itens(202)

Comment: No que o @Maniero comentou, lá naquele post estão dizendo que LINQ é mais lento que For/Foreach, mas melhorou bastante a performance usando linq ao invés de foreach no meu caso, e agora?

Comment: Você está usando EF?

Comment: @Maniero, sim eu uso EF

Comment: Então é diferente, nem deveria ter cogitado usar de outra forma, o EF vai converter isso em *query* em vez de trazer tudo e processar na memória. Se você não coloca essa informação totalmente relevante e necessárias fica complicado responder adequadamente.

Comment: @Maniero, valeu. Realmente "comi touca", "pisei na redonda".

Answer (score 3):

fiz isso e ganhei muito. Agora está com uns 3s para executar, o que levava mais de 2min.

```
var catalogs = _catalogService.GetAllByResellerId(resellerId).Select(c => new MarkupListResponse
            {
                CreatedOn = c.CatalogDate,
                CatalogId = c.Id,
                ItemsQuantity = c.Items.Count()
            }).ToList();

            return Ok(catalogs);
```

Comment: Entenda, que nesse caso, muito provavelmente não é expressão lambda que melhorou a sua performance... mas sim a query gerada para consultar o banco de dados.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, faz sentido o que você disse, mas essas coisas são muito conceituais, por exemplo, para iterar e enviar uma query ao banco, dizem que Linq/Lambda é mais performático, pelo que tenho lido. Iterar uma lista, creio que o foreach/for seja mais performático, pelo que acabei de ler no post de um amigo meu. Como disseram, depende de como e no que usar.

Comment: Faça o teste, compare queries anteriores e a atual