# Padrões de programação com segurança e simplicidade

Tags: php, javascript, estilo-de-codificação

*Talvez essa pergunta soe ampla mas no fundo não é, eu ainda não sou formada em nada então só tenho as más práticas nas costas e queria aprender a programar de uma forma não apenas "padrão" e sim clara e limpa.*

---

**Padrões de programação com segurança e simplicidade**

Veja, quando eu digo padrões de programação me refiro a forma de escrever o código de uma forma saudável e simples... Lendo e pesquisando eu encontrei algumas dicas que podem ajudar, tais são:

1. Escrever as variáveis de forma descritiva curta e seguindo o modelo de "corcunda de camelo" **Ex:** `$userBrowser = $_SERVER...`
2. Comentar o código, mas fazer comentários breves e descritivos afim de uma futura manutenção
3. Ser simplista na hora de fazer acontecer, digo, fazer o código da forma fácil sem perder a eficiência

eu conheci essas três, devem ter outras.. Se você sabe outras cite **no máximo 3** que não estejam listadas acima...

**e a segurança, onde entra?**

Bem, eu tenho pequeno tique com segurança, medo talvez e como sempre estou a programar do lado do servidor *(ex: PHP)* e do cliente *(ex: JS)* eu fico extremamente preocupado com esse quesito. Segurança é um assunto muito amplo, então vamos resumir na "segurança da programação", não sei ao certo como nomear o que eu direi mas veja essa situação:

***esse exemplo é extremamente metafórico com fins explicativos.***

Suponhamos que seja disposto 10 cachorros distintos em uma array.

Um while irá íterar essa array e jogará cada ítem, *cachorro*, em uma função para verificar os atributos do animal.

```
while....
checaAtributos(cachorro)....
....
```

a função `checaAtributos` faz isso:

```
function checaAtributos(cachorro) {
   if(cachorro.lenght == 0) // verifica se a variável cachorro está vazia...

   var corDosOlhos = checaCorDosOlhos(cachorro);
   ....
```

na função `checaCorDosOlhos` eu precisarei checar novamente se a variável `cachorro` está vazia? É necessário?

**Resumindo:** uma vez verificado certos parâmetros terei que verifica-los novamente se eu passar de uma função para outra?

Eu acho que é isso, se tiveres algo mais a acrescentar-me ficarei grata

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. É relacionada a algum paradigma em específico (orientado a objetos, procedural)? Ficou confuso também o que exatamente você se refere com segurança. Eu tenho um entendimento bem diferente do exposto no exemplo.

Comment: @gmsantos Oi, seria no geral mesmo, sem ser especifico. Eu coloquei a palavra "segurança" mas eu não sei ao certo se essa palavra é a certa a se utilizar.. Por isso criei aquele pequeno exemplo. Exponha o seu entendimento para eu lhe explicar..

Comment: Acho que [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=boas%20pr%C3%A1ticas) tem um bom ponto de partida. Edit: [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13890/como-escrever-um-c%C3%B3digo-leg%C3%ADvel-e-de-f%C3%A1cil-manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o/14275#14275) por exemplo é excelente, talvez até uma duplicata desta... Mas a pergunta é boa, dei +1 e espero que apareçam boas respostas (e agora ainda vi que é especifica sobre javascript, legal)...

Comment: @gustavox esse "artigo" é muito bom, abriu minha mente.. agora me resta aguardar sobre o outro ponto da minha pergunta.. Obrigada!

Comment: Procure pelos livros, clean code, programador pragmatico, code complete, como ser um bom programador e a arte de escrever programas legíveis eles tem dezenas desses tipos de dicas.

Comment: Simplesmente _amplo de mais_, porque falar de boas práticas é uma coisa, e segurança é também outra, por mais que sejam pequenas abordagens ainda assim são demasiado extensas porque possuem demasiados pontos a serem tidos em atenção, porque ás vezes é difícil explicar uma parte sem ter de explicar outra. Aconselho que procures pelo _google_, cá existem também algumas perguntas já respondias que talvez te mostrem o caminho por onde começar a focar.

Comment: inviável responder aqui... Uma resposta caberia num livro e mesmo assim teria muita base em opiniões, conceitos específicos, etc. Ou seria algo vago, abordando superficialmente diversos conceitos...

Comment: tudo bem.. ....