# Quero colocar o número dos caracteres e colocar se ele par ou ímpar

Tags: c#, .net, string

Mas meu código está dando erro.

```
namespace Impar_ou_parr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string NumLetras;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");
            NumLetras = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Sua palavrra tem " + NumLetras.Length + " letras!");

            int x;
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero par de letras");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero impar de letras");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de erro e onde está ocorrendo o mesmo?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida. Diga o erro, o que deveria acontecer, porque precisa pegar esse valor de `x`.

Comment: x = NumLetras.(Console.ReadLine()); está dando erro n sei porque

Comment: não deveria ser x = int.Parse(NumLetras.Length), para x receber o tamanho da palavra?

Comment: x = int.Parse(NumLetras.Length), continua dando erro, eu ja tinha tentado

Comment: Qual o erro que esta aparecendo?

Comment: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Comment: ah, x = NumLetras.Length

Comment: NumLetras.Lenght ja retorna um int, não precisava do parse

Comment: @Genezis não adicione detalhes da pargunta nos comentários. Edite sua pergunta e ponha os comentário lá. Assim qdo alguém, com o mesmo problema, for ler, irá entender todo cenário apenas pela pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso você n precisa dá um `int.Parse`, pois o mesmo já é um inteiro. Além disso você não precisa buscar o valor novamente no console, pois você já tem sua palavra na variável  `NumLetras`. Dito isso tente o código abaixo, rodou na minha maquina

```
namespace Impar_ou_parr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string NumLetras;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");
            NumLetras = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Sua palavrra tem " + NumLetras.Length + " letras!");

            int x;
            x = NumLetras.Length;
            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero par de letras");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero impar de letras");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NICE, foi muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que deseja isto:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Impar_ou_parr {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");
            WriteLine($"Sua palavra tem um numero {(ReadLine().Length % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "ímpar")} de letras");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PUMf7O). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mVfrp8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ReadLineIncorrect.cs).

Dei uma modernizada, organizada e limpada no código.

Não tinha porque pedir um número para saber se é par, tinha que pegar o tamanho da palavra para ver se é par ou ímpar.

Comment: Daora essa sua modernizada organizada e limpada, foi!

Comment: Se fosse manter mais ou menos na forma original, procure usar nomes de variáveis que dê significado ao que ela faz e use convenções de nomenclatura. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101. Evite declarar a variável e atribuir depois e criar variáveis desnecessárias.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Impar_ou_parr { class Program { static void Main(string[] args) { string NumLetras;

    Console.WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");

    NumLetras = Console.ReadLine();
    int letrasTotal = NumLetras.Lenght;
  Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem " + letrasTotal + " letras!");


    if (letrasTotal % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero par de letras");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero impar de letras");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'NumLetras' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Genezis eu editei a resposta agora, veja se funciona agora

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seria isto:

```
namespace Impar_ou_parr { 
class Program { 
static void Main(string[] args) { 
string Palavra;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");

        Palavra = Console.ReadLine();
        int x;
        x = Palavra.Length;
      Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem " + x + " letras!");


        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero par de letras");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero impar de letras");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Foi! Vlw ai!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string NumLetras;
    Console.WriteLine("Digite uma Palavra: ");
    NumLetras = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Sua palavrra tem " + NumLetras.Length + " letras!");

    int x;
    int.TryParse(NumLetras.Length.ToString(),out x);
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero par de letras");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sua palavra tem um numero impar de letras");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Pra que converter um número para `string` para depois convertê-lo para número de novo?